# How do i use Log.d in react-native native module?

Tags: java, react-native, logging, logcat, native-module

I want to see when certain methods get fired inside a native module.

I've imported

```
import android.util.Log;
```

in the java file that I want to write my log to.

Here's the method I would like to log.

```
public void play(int frequency, double duration, double amplitude, int mode) {
        BlueManager blueManager = BLueServiceManager.getSharedBlueManager();
        if (blueManager == null || !blueManager.isConnected()) {
            return;
        }

        byte actualFreq = (byte) (frequency / EQ_STEP_SIZE);
        short actualDuration = (short) (duration * 1800);
        blueManager.playTone(actualFreq, actualDuration, amplitude);
    }
```

I've attempted to add

```
Log.d("is this thing working???", "I certainly hope so");
```

inside the method.

I have Android Studio open and I'm looking at the Logcat window. I don't see my message anywhere even though I know that I've accessed that method.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside Logcat, I can see, you've selected only "info" messages to display.

[image]

`Log.d()` stands for debug messages, So, will not come under "info"(`Log.i()`) messages.

Change it and select "**Debug**". You'll see the message. Or select "**Verbose**" to see all the messages, whichever type.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your app on a real device :

`Log.d('Notification', 'Log from the app');`

you should start listening log by the command :

`adb logcat -s Notification:D`

Notice that 1st parameter in Log.d, a TAG for logcat command.

Complete docs here : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat?hl=fr

Comment: Need to use double quotes in Log.d